# Can a webservice written in Symfony2 regognize if the user who is calling the webservice is logged in?

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, restful-authentication

I have a B2C application coded in Symfony2. Users arrives on my homepage and then signup. Once signup, my application authenticate this user, using the Authentication of Symfony 2. The authentication is persistent, so after the signup the user will be loggedin "forever".

But my users can interact with my application not only directly under my domain: there are websites, partners of my application, that allows their users to interact with my application. During this, the user remains inside the pages of the third party website.

In order to make this possible I've created, in Symfony, a set of API that allows third party websites to interact with my application. The API calls are made by Jquery.

Here comes my question: would my Symfony Controller who replies to API Calls, be able to recognize if the user who is on the third party website which is doing the API call is loggedin on my application or not?

I tried to check this:

if($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')){

But it always replies me with false.

If the API Call would have been made by PHP, I know it would be impossible. But it is made in JavaScript, so from the client (the user). That's why I think I would be able to recognize if the client who is calling my API from a third party website, is already loggedin on my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a SSO Solution. I've just implemented SSO in one of my projects using [SamlSPBundle](https://github.com/aerialship/SamlSPBundle/) and [SimpleSamlPhp](https://simplesamlphp.org/). You would have to setup SimpleSamlPhp as an Identity Provider and all the participating Websites who want to use SSO as Service providers.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this!